# Keep Record of Anonymous user Django

Tags: django

I want to keep record of Anonymous user action on my wishlistwebsite. and want to keep sync with django server. what will be best way to do that ? till Now I came across way using localstorage of browser but its not effective in some cases like keeping record of guest user wishlist's etc .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django makes use of a `Session` object with a `session_key` as primary key, this is also the value you can obtain with `request.session.session_key`.

You thus can make a `ForeignKey` to the `Session` object the user is currently working on. The advantage of this is that if the `Session` is cleaned up, then all the data that is stored in that session will be removed as well.

So if you have a `MyModel` you wish to link to a session, you can use:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # …
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

You can obtain the session key with:

```
# add a record
if not request.session.session_key:
    request.session.create()
session_id = request.session.session_key
MyModel.objects.create(session_id=session_id)
```

Beware that sessions can expire, or "inacessible" if the user clears their browser cookies. Although storing data related to a session is not inherently a bad idea, it is not very *persistent*.

Comment: Thanks for answer , there is confusion I have to save this key in browser local storage ? so that I will check everytime if is this the same user or not ?

Comment: @gamer: well Django's sessions will store a cookie at the client browser that contains the session id. Cookies are each time send when a browser makes a request, so there is no addional overhead, it is already in the request. You do not have to implement saving that yourself: Django's session middleware handles that accordingly.

Comment: thanks got it . if I am not wrong its time we can set in settings.py  SESSION_COOKIE_AGE = 5 * 60   like this ?

Comment: @gamer: that is correct. But beware that the browser of a user can of course *ignore* this, and decide to clean it up after 1 hour for example. After all, the data is stored in the browser, so the browser decided what to store and for how long.

Comment: Sir I saw a website like  getyouguide.com it saves wishlist like more then one day. is there anyway to keep things for a long time ?

Comment: @gamer: what if you make a wishlist, clear the cookies and cache of that website, and visit the site again?

Comment: yes sir on clearing cache and cookie wishlist is empty .

Comment: but only on firefox . on chrome I cleared last hour data and that is still there

Comment: @gamer: so it clearly also uses a cookie. You can specify the `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`. I'm only saying that some browsers can ignore that. For example in Firefox you can say that all the cookies need to be removed when you close the browser.

Comment: @gamer: well the session cookie is likely there from the moment you visited the site (or at least in the first time of the last month for example).

Comment: alright thanks for guiding me till here .just didnt get last line  ( or at least in the first time of the last month for example)  so in chrome its saving my session from like for example 1 month ? I am right ?

Comment: @gamer: that is possible. With a "cookie browser" you can often see when the cookie was constructed, and how long it takes before it expires.

Comment: thanks for you precious time sir <3 stay blessed always . I will try this method